# store the index of an element in an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am trying to store indexes of 1's and 0's in this array:

```
arr = [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.
 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
```

with this for loop ind_0 and ind_1 being lists:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
if arr[i]==0:
    ind_0.append(arr.index[i])

if arr[i]==1:
    ind_1.append(arr.index[i])
```

I get an error which says `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`.
The question is how can I store the indexes of the elements in an array? Is my way of doing wrong?Any help is appreciated

Comment: please fix your indexing. It also appears you are using numpy arrays. Is that your intention? If it is, just do `ind_1 = np.argwhere(arr==1)`, `ind_0 = np.argwhere(arr==0)`

Comment: Think a little more, especially about the variable `i`... How do you use it when you check e.g. `arr[i] == 0`? Don't you use it as an index already? So why not append `i` to your lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering you want to save indexes of 0s and 1s in `ind_0` and `ind_1`

You do not need to use any index here as i is already the index when you check arr[i] :

```py
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == 0:
        ind_0.append(i)

    if arr[i] == 1:
        ind_1.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with your question is that you haven't told the whole story.  There's another step, where you convert `arr` from a Python to a numpy array.  As it turns out, numpy has a function to return the indices of all nonzero elements directly:

```
ind_1 = arr.nonzero()
ind_0 = (1-arr).nonzero()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do using enumerate.

```
idx_0 = []
idx_1 = []
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if v == 1:
        idx_1.append(i)
        continue
    idx_0.append(i)
```